# how to automate git clone in Dockerfile?

Tags: git, docker

Would I like to create a script on the dockerfile that clones github repositorio for my current director, some and have a solution?

that's my current dockerfile!

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN git clone https://github.com/username/myrepo.git
WORKDIR /usr/app
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

instead of cloning the repositorio via the command line, I need have some script/process that when running make the gitclone of the repositories and save them in the services folder.

[image] it is my repositori, if i run command git clone myrepository.git , will clone my repositorio straight into that folder, I want to do this from automated forming within a Dockerfile

Comment: Anything not working with this? Why did you add tags for Javascript and n, but none for Docker?

Comment: actually I do not know exactly how to do this process, if it shows some example code, thanks!

Comment: is it public or private repo ? also is there reason why dockerfile is outside of repo ?

Comment: my reputation on github still does not make the docker tag available to me. i'm new here

Comment: You will probably want to swap the RUN and WORKDIR lines, but aside from that, you'd need to provide more details on what exactly it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: the repositorio is private being that I have access, the docker file is out because precisely I want to perform the git clone into the current repo running only the dockerfile

Comment: at first my goal is to make a gitclone via docker into the current folder

Comment: If you want to clone into the "current folder", you mean the current folder on the host system running the docker command?

Comment: current folder i mean the same folder where this my file dockerfile

Comment: We need to have some script / process that when running make the gitclone of the repositories and save them in the folder

Comment: "I do not know exactly how to do this process" - what does that mean? What **exactly** is not working with the given approach? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section

Comment: I think there is a slight misconception about what a Dockerfile does. Building a Dockerfile will result in an image for a container. The process of building an image will not modify your working directory at all.

Comment: yes, but the Dockerfile alse automatize process of clone repositories

Comment: Next time, instead of adding details as an answer to your question, edit the question to edit the details there. Best is to provide some examples, even an example with a public repository would do.
But based on what I think you want, try if this command to see if it does what you need (no Dockerfile needed, needs to run in an empty directory): `docker run --rm --entrypoint "sh" -v $(pwd):/var/repo -w /var/repo node:16 -c 'git clone https://REPLACE.ME/repo/url .'`

Comment: I should note that if this command does indeed do what you need, then a Dockerfile will not do the trick

Comment: i think i explained it better

Comment: "the Dockerfile alse automatize process of clone repositories" - what do you mean by that? It builds a container, yeah. But if you want to work with the source code, you need to check it out in any other way

Comment: exactly that, i want to work with the source code

Comment: Then why not run `git clone` on your machine? A Docker file is not some kind of binary that does this for you

Comment: understood, is found no example, thanks very much.